# SQL bind_param not working

Tags: sql, mysqli

I am using mysqli with `bind_param` on my code but I keep getting the error:

number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

but the parameters match variables. any idea?

here is my code:

```
$fromDate = "2014-06-26";
$toDate = "2014-06-26";    
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateUpdated, '%d/%m/%Y'), source_id, count(*) FROM kb_news WHERE dateUpdated BETWEEN 'fromDate 00:00:00' AND 'toDate 23:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(dateUpdated), source_id;";

if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $fromDate, $toDate);
```

Thanks

Comment: You have no placeholder specified. Where you would like to bind the values?

Answer (score 1):

You query must look like .

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateUpdated, '%d/%m/%Y'), source_id, count(*) FROM kb_news WHERE dateUpdated BETWEEN '? 00:00:00' AND '? 23:59:59' GROUP BY DATE(dateUpdated), source_id;";
```

You have to use question mark as placeholder instead of names.

Comment: Even when I replace the variables in the query with placeholders ? I get the same erros